# Can this code be done in less steps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, math

I have a problem with thinking something is much more difficult than it really is.  So I was just wondering if there is a shorter way of writing my code. Basically just want to let a user know how hot || cold they are but felt like I did it in way too many lines of code. And is Math.abs() the easiest way to convert every number to a positive? Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

```
$("#guessButton").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        counter++;
        $('#count').text(counter);
        var guess = $('#userGuess').val();
        if (guess == number) {
            $('#feedback').text("You've guessed the number!!");
            $('#guessList').append("<li>"+guess+"</li>");
        } else if (Math.abs(number-guess) <= 50 && Math.abs(number-guess) >= 30) {
            $('#feedback').text("Cold");
            $('#guessList').append("<li>"+guess+"</li>");
        } else if (Math.abs(number-guess) <= 30 && Math.abs(number-guess) >= 20) {
            $('#feedback').text("Warm");
            $('#guessList').append("<li>"+guess+"</li>");
        } else if (Math.abs(number-guess) <= 20 && Math.abs(number-guess) >= 10) {
            $('#feedback').text("Hot");
            $('#guessList').append("<li>"+guess+"</li>");
        } else if (Math.abs(number-guess) <= 10 && Math.abs(number-guess) >= 1) {
            $('#feedback').text("Very Hot");
            $('#guessList').append("<li>"+guess+"</li>");
        } else if (Math.abs(number-guess) > 50) {
            $('#feedback').text("Ice Cold");
            $('#guessList').append("<li>"+guess+"</li>");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ewww...First of all save Math.abs(number-guess) to a variable.

Comment: This question is more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: yes, in lots of ways. a couple: 1. don't repeat yourself, for example you calc  `Math.abs(number-guess)` several times, when you can do it once up top and name the result _diff_.  2. look into _switch_. 3. build the output into a string and then call `$('#guessList').append` at the bottom with that string instead of having all those calls mid-block.

Comment: Basically you're calculating the distance of the user's guess with the number and then map the distance to a string. How about using a map of "max distance --> string" ordered ascendingly by max distance and using this to convert the calculated distance to a string?

Comment: Ahhh got it. Truly appreciate the suggestions but were the down votes necessary lol. I thought it would help a lot of us newbs to ask newb type questions. But no worries I will not do it in this forum next time. Hopefully one day I can be on your guy's level. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick response to your question that I think might help. I made a few assumptions about global variables but should help for the most part I hope.

```
$("#guessButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    counter++; //ill assume this is global
    $('#count').text(counter);

    var feedBack;
    var guess = $('#userGuess').val();
    var absVal = Math.abs(number-guess); //ill assume number is global

    if (guess == number) {
        feedBack = "You've guessed the number!!";

    }else if (absVal > 50) {
        feedBack = "Ice Cold";

    }else if (absVal >= 30) {
        feedBack = "Cold";

    } else if (absVal >= 20) {
        feedBack = "Warm";

    } else if (absVal >= 10) {
        feedBack = "Hot";

    } else if (absVal >= 1) {
        feedBack = "Very Hot";

    } 

    $('#feedback').text(feedBack);
    $('#guessList').append("<li>"+guess+"</li>");
});
```